# Not able to save two lists mapped to a text file - python

Tags: python, save, text-parsing

Currently, I am trying to save a list of numbers that I have been able to map to a different list. It works well when I print it :) - but when I try and save it to a text file I am getting an error.

This is the code when it works:

```
print (*map(numbers.__getitem__, names), sep=",")
```

However, when I try and literally try and save the outcome above to a `txt` file I am getting an error:`invalid syntax` - not sure why.

This is the code for saving it to a `txt file`:

```
file = open("contacts.txt","w")  
file.write(*map(numbers.__getitem__, names), sep=",")
file.close()
```

Would really be happy if someone could help me here - I don't get how I am able to print to a terminal but not able to save that end result to a text file

@wim, I tried the following code below:

```
with file.open("contacts.txt","w") as f: 
    print(*map(numbers.__getitem__, names), sep=",", file=f)
    file.close()
```

it is saying that `file` is not declared! Doesn't work

Comment: What error are you getting *exactly*. I would expect a `TypeError` not a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` accepts multiple arguments.  `file.write` does not.

Try this instead:

```
with open('contacts.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(*map(numbers.__getitem__, names), sep=",", file=f)
```

Or, use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: That would produce a `TypeError`, not a `SyntaxError`, though

Comment: Right, but the OP is reporting a `SyntaxError`, although clearly what you've stated stands.

Comment: @wim +10000000 THANKS A MILLION MAN - LIFESAVER & LEGEND! ACCEPTED ANSWER ANY DAY BRO!!!

Comment: No problem, Mr Agdgagsgasdjiafd.